# Hibernate complains about double single quote

Tags: sql, hibernate, escaping

I am trying to select some data using Hibernate
The query ends up as follows

```
"select mystuff from mytable where upper(mystuff)=upper('a''c')"
```

( a'c is comming from user input escaped by `StringEscapeUtils.escapeSql()`)

Hibernate is giving me a SQLGrammarException. Did I escape that single quote wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think `''` to escape `'` is good. I suppose that Hibernate + some RDBMS can have some mistakes with those quotes escaping. You should try to use `preparedStatement` or `Query` [interface of Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html). To inject you data with method like this :

```
String selectSQL = "select mystuff from mytable where upper(mystuff)=upper(?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
preparedStatement.setString(1, "a'c");
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(selectSQL);
while (rs.next()) {
    String mystuff = rs.getString("mystuff");
}
```

Or like this :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from mytable where upper(mystuff)=upper(:mystuff)");
query.setString("mystuff", "a'c");
List<?> list = query.list();
```

So hibernate will be able to handle it.

Hope it helps :)